# Why aren't the tags and attributes we send displayed in the ET dashboard despite being visible in our logs?

Tags: dashboard, mobilesdk, android, sfdcmobilesdk-android, mobilepush

We are testing our integration of Exact Target on Android and are unable to see the data we are sending in the Exact Target dashboard.

We have verified that the data is being sent by looking at the device logs:

```
Success Response: {"platform":"Android","device_Token":"APA91bExln-p1-opO_BeQitKvJCWnDUcG1PrJY-KTRdH-kzHUhgIQeemy7mKfP7AjQ2uVMzO0-Te8fURzfhpxEz7_d_ljiMaXM_FFq9WNICwJ2yTyCvsF0Cc9KnxCLjcOXVI_6HncA7u277Psdid0jgMpz1du4_0jw","deviceID":"24122f80a80105d58c3684a66952fd22","etAppId":"1905c032-3b93-4d8a-bfb8-811cf3d50b76","timeZone":"0","dST":true,"tags":["DocumentCompleted:com.rbi.nsan.issue.22112014","ALL","DocumentCompleted:com.rbi.nsan.issue.19042014","EditionOpened:com.rbi.nsan.issue.22112014","EditionOpened:com.rbi.nsan.issue.19042014","Debug","Android"],"attributes":[{"key":"_ETSDKVersion","value":"3.4.1"},{"key":"LastDownloadCompleted","value":"30/04/2015_10:14:34"},{"key":"LastFreeDownloadCompleted","value":"30/04/2015_10:14:34"}],"platform_Version":"5.0.2","subscriberKey":"24122f80a80105d58c3684a66952fd22","push_Enabled":true,"location_Enabled":false,"hwid":"asus Nexus 7","language":"en_GB","gcmSenderId":"401534812251"}
```

And also by proxy-ing the device to check the call to fire off the data is going through. [image: Charles Proxy log]

We have been checking for the attributes and tags on the dashboard by the following means:
1. looking up the contact details for a specific device ID and checking the list of attributes associated with this contact
2. creating a contact list based on a tag and seeing what devices are included in the list

Please could you advise if there is any issue with the output we are sending which would explain why we aren't seeing the data for our attributes and tags on the dashboard.

Thanks

Comment: The "Success Response" you receive is an acknowledgement that we received your message and your original request is mirrored back to you.  Our services team should have a response regarding the actual entries being added (or not) to your MC console.

Comment: Did you remove the underscore from your date fields and did this resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The underscore is not valid in your dates.

```
    {
        "key": "LastDownloadCompleted",
        "value": "30/04/2015_10:14:34"
    },
    {
        "key": "LastFreeDownloadCompleted",
        "value": "30/04/2015_10:14:34"
    }
```

That is causing your issue.